# kendo-ui dropdownlist updating after open

Tags: drop-down-menu, kendo-ui

I want to get the data source for the drop down list from server only after 
opening the combo.

I thought on two options:
the first is to refresh the opened list, how can I do it?

or the other one, to get the event before opening the drop down list, and not opening it,
and when I receive the data from server to open it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is done for you, have a look at autoBind property : http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/dropdownlist#configuration-autoBind

```
$("#dropdownlist").kendoDropDownList({
    autoBind: false
});
```

Comment: This does not seem to work in this manner if the ddl is cascaded.